# Easy built-in way in Azure DevOps to get a separate published pipeline artifact from another pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

For example, I have a build pipeline that is triggered on pull requests and merges to main. The pipeline publishes a build artifact whenever it runs.

What I want to do is download the artifact published in the pull request triggered pipeline in the 'main' triggered pipeline.

Is there a built in or similarly simple way to download the "pull request" artifact in the "main" triggered pipeline?

Comment: What is your objective here? Why would you want an artifact from PR validation during a run from a stable branch?

Comment: In my case, the pull request artifact is effectively a snapshot of values from another resource during the pull request. What I'm trying to avoid is the pipeline grabbing the incorrect snapshot values. Let's say person A opens a PR and then the person B opens a PR and merges in their changes (which will modify the resource's values). If then person A merges in their change the "main" triggered pipeline will take a snapshot of the resource with both person A & B's changes. I only want the values of the snapshot when person A opened their pull request.

Comment: The build artifacts created by a pipeline can be used in other pipelines. See "[Publish and download pipeline Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)".